# Circular Motion - System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

The following system of differential equations describes a charged particle in a viscous medium enveloped in an EM field,
$$\partial^2_t x(t) = a\cos(\omega t +\phi)y +bx +c\partial_t y -d\partial_t x$$
$$\partial^2_t y(t) = a\cos(\omega t +\phi)x +by -c\partial_t x -d\partial_t y$$

All of the coefficients are real and positive. It's well known there are two circular eigenmotions. Given this, it seems useful to make the change of variables $u(t)=x(t)+i y(t)$. Doing so produces,
$$\partial^2_t u(t) = ai\cos(\omega t +\phi)u^* +bu -(d+ic)\partial_t u$$

In the case of $a=d=0$, a solution of $u(t)=\exp(-iw_0t)$ exists with $w_0$ holding two values based on $b$ and $c$. It can be assumed $\partial_t x(0)=\partial_t y(0)=0$

Any suggestions on how to proceed further? If it makes the problem significantly easier, the case of $d=0$ is also of great interest.

Comment: What if you subtract the two equations and solve for the variable $z(t)=x(t)-y(t)$ could it be of any help? Edit: just noticed that the first partial derivative with respect to time don't have the same sign so probably it wouldn't help...maybe choosing a new variable $e=-c$ just for the second equation?

Comment: How do you define $\rho_1$, $\rho_2$, etc?

Comment: @Robert, I've updated the question to clarify

Comment: What's the question? I can only see statements.

Comment: @md2perpe, thanks